# How do I output a 2d array correctly in c++ with if states within?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have to write a code for a 2d maze game with output in the terminal.
So my problem is that I have a text file with 6 values (index for goal, start and max size of array) which looks like this

```
5 7
2 0
2 6
*******
* * * *
  *
*   ***
*******
```

I already had the right output but if I want to replace one of the blank spaces with a character to mark the start point I get this

```
 *******
* * *S*
  *
*   ***
```

here is my code:

```
ifstream mazeFile("mazeExample.txt", std::ios_base::in);
int height, width, heightStart, widthStart, heightGoal, widthGoal;
int playerX, playerY;

void readMaze(){
char map[height][width];

mazeFile >> height;
mazeFile >> width;
mazeFile >> heightStart;
mazeFile >> widthStart;
mazeFile >> heightGoal;
mazeFile >> widthGoal;

for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        mazeFile.get(map[y][x]);
        if (!(x == widthStart && y == heightStart))
        {
        }else{
            map[y][x] = 'S';
        }
        cout << map[y][x];
    }
}
```

I dont get why it inserts the 'S' in between instead of replacing the blank space at the given index. Other solutions didn't work out and I don't want to just copy their code.

Comment: `char map[height][width]` is definitely wrong, since you're not even assigning values to `height` or `width` at this point.

Comment: I already tried  to initialize my char map after my ifstream assigns values but it still doesnt work out

Comment: `char map[height][width];` -- To start with, this is not valid C++ code.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by compile-time values, not runtime values.  A dynamic 2D array is easily done by using `std::vector<std::vector<char>> map(height, std::vector<char>(width));`.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, at least you are brave!

```
// creates a 2D Variable Length Array with current values for height and width
char map[height][width];
// loads (but a bit late) the values for the variables which have just been used above
mazeFile >> height;
mazeFile >> width;
```

More seriously, this is a terrible piece of C++ code. VLA are not supported in standard C++ and are only supported as extensions by gcc. Moreover, they are generally avoided because they may not be exception safe. And last but not least, the dimensions are used **at declaration time**.

What to do here:

1. the minimum is to only declare the array when its dimensions are known

   ```
    void readMaze(){

    mazeFile >> height;
    mazeFile >> width;
    char map[height][width];
   ```

   yet this is not conformant C++ code
2. or go the C++ way and replace C-ish VLAs with vectors

   ```
    cin>>height;
    cin>>width;
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> map(height);
    for(auto v: map) {
        v = std::vector<char>(width);
    }
   ```

   This one is correct C++ code and should work on any C++ system...